# How to calculate mean value in a dictionary?

Tags: dictionary, mean

I'm trying to compute the mean value of a dictionary which have lot of lists

My dictionary looks like:

```
{0:[0,1,3,6,1,-5,....],1:[0,3,7,3,-5,2,...],...}
```

with a total of k entries and lists of lenght N.

However, I am NOT trying to compute the mean value of each list, what I need is to compute the mean value bewteen elements of the lists such (a,b)=mean, i.e. looking at the dictionary above (0,0)=0, (1,3)=2, (3,7)=5,....

Is there a way to compute something like this?

Thanks.

Comment: What language? For say two lists, zip the lists and for each element in the zipped list, apply addition on its two components and divide by two. E.g. for python using `zip(...)` and list comprehension: `elementwise_mean_of_0_and_1_keys = [(a+b)/2.0 for a, b in zip(dict[0], dict[1])]` (assuming the lists for both is the same), producing `[0.0, 2.0, 5.0, 4.5, -2.0, -1.5, ...]`.

Comment: How would you like to get the result? As a list of means?

Comment: @dfri What about the mean for 100 lists? Is there a way to extend the zip(a,b) from just 2 lists?

Comment: @Mureinik yes, I would need a list of means, because I need to plot the value of each list and the mean in a graphic (all the lists have the same lenght, so does the mean list.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can unwrap the values and use `zip` to correlate matching indexes:

```
from numpy import mean
result = [mean(x) for x in zip(*(d.values()))]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that all lists are of the same length:

```
var k = Object.keys(json).length; // k, number of lists
var n = json[0].length;           // N, elements in lists

for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var sum = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < k; j++) {
        sum += json[j][i];
    }
    var mean = sum / k;

    console.log(mean);
}
```